# Adding a circle on an imagei n Android

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have on a project the following Image defined in the Layout-Main:

```xml
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/compass"/>
```

This Image View represents a compass and I would like to add over the image an indication showing the Direction to follow.
Actually the image rotates to indicate the North direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make images for each of the directions and change them according to your needs in the MainActivity.

Comment: hope you got it